# PredictionIO adding new algorithms

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, cloud, predictionio

I am thinking of using PredictionIO for building my machine learning system and i can't seem to find any documents which can tell me how to add new algorithms to the system (Excluding algos from MLib).

If anybody does have any knowledge of this please share.